# SQL - Sqlite Query: obtain the fields where one number is greater than another, if less than 3 complete with the first, always 3

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, union

Well i made a query  that is not working

i have a table like this

_id      - E1 
    -----------
1    -  100 
2    -  335
3    -  420
4    -  440
5    -  500
6    -  514
7    -  524
8    -  534
9    -  544
10   -  552
11   -  559
12   -  607
13   -  615
14   -  623
15   -  631
16   -  639

and the query that i made:

`SELECT * FROM
      (SELECT * FROM Table WHERE E1 > 633 AND _sentido = 'V' 
          UNION
       SELECT * FROM Table) LIMIT 3`

when i execute this i get

_id - E1 
    -----------
1    -  100 
2    -  335
3    -  420

but what i really want is

_id - E1 
    -----------
1    -  639 
2    -  100
3    -  335

if the last row and there are NOT 3 selected rows then complete with the first to reach 3

Always 3 rows!

I hope you can help me, John

Comment: When you say `complete with the first`... what order are you using to say `first`? Also if only one result is fetched from the original filter, then are you expecting to have the `first` value twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a clever approach, but it is not going to work.  The ordering of subqueries is not guaranteed.  What you want is to order by your condition first and then fill out with the rest.  Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY (case when E1 > 633 AND _sentido = 'V' then 1 else 2 end)
LIMIT 3;
```

This puts the records you are interested in first.  The `limit 3` will retrieve those records (up to 3) and then pad remaining rows with the rest of the records.